# Is this notation common in Calculus?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, notation

Okay this is going to be quite a stupid question, but to me this seems... wrong, or at the very least not completely correct.

In the material I'm reading there's a part that states that $y$ evolves as follows:

$dy = u(t,x) - u(t + dt, x + \mu dx) + R + z$ (where $R$ and $z$ just some arbitrary terms).

and later it says that when $dy = 0$ and as $x$ moves to $x + dx$ we can write:

$du = R + z$

My question is whether this type of notation is common in papers (or whether this is an abuse of notation), because it doesn't seem correct to me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's just a short form,not an abuse of notation. Especially common in mathematical physics.

Comment: Really? But what if this notation could potentially affect later equations? I mean I do believe you because the later equations make sense by writing it this way but it just seems wrong since it isn't completely 'correct'...